# SQLite 12 times slower on Mac than Windows

Tags: macos, sqlite, delphi, firedac

My app uses FireDAC (Delphi XE7) to access SQLite.

The Mac version is about 12 times slower than the Windows version.

I have journal_mode turned off, and no journal files appear.

The only difference I can see is that the Mac has checkpoint_fullfsync turned on by default (it's turned off by default in Windows). I've turned it off on the Mac but the 12X slowdown persists.

The Mac is the latest Yosemite. SQLite3 -version reports 3.8.5.

Windows 7 is using whatever version of SQLite3 is baked into FireDAC.

What would cause such a huge difference in performance?

Comment: Are all the details needed to answer this question present?

Comment: Do the Mac and Windows versions happen to run on different CPUs/disks/file systems/memories/OSes?

Comment: You really need to supply more information.  I am surprised that the question has not been voted for closure.  For instance, versions of everything - sqllite, windows, mac os, hardware of both machines.  Dump of settings of each instance.  Your metadata and code.

Comment: I could have been more clear. All the pragmas are identical for OS X and Windows 7. The ones I concentrated on are...

Driver Name: SQLIte
journal_mode         off
encoding             UTF-8
checkpoint_fullfsync 0
fullfsync            0
temp_store           0
synchronous          0
wal_autocheckpoint   1000
temp_store           0
quick_check          ok

Comment: The workaround is to set FDConnection.ResourceOptions.SilentMode to True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on tests done by folks by product testers working with Embarcadero, including comparisons to UNIDac using the same queries, the 12X slowdown has something to the way FireDAC uses transactions. The issue has been added to Embarcadero's bug reporting system and it was duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

As da-soft said in their comment, setting FDConnection.ResourceOptions.SilentMode to True solves the issue. Queries are now ten times faster on OSX.

Comment: why SilentMode can  solve this problem